# How to get data from different table in CGridView?

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have 3 tables.
car_types:

```
id | main_image | title
```

car_type_classifiers:

```
id | car_type_id | classifier_id
```

classifiers:

```
id | class
```

I want to display a CGridView so there are columns: Title | class. But Classes can be many for one car_type. I tried to search online, but couldn't understand those `$criteria->compare()` functions in model search function.

I want those to show up as little lists. How can I do that?
my view:

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'car-type-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
        'columns' => array(
                'title'
    ),
));
```

my controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model=new EeCarTypes('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();

    $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

and my model:

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('car_type',$this->car_type,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you model has the good relations.

In your view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'car-type-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns' => array(
        'title',
        array(            
            'name'=>'Class',
            'type' => 'raw',
            //call the method 'gridDataColumn' from the controller
            'value'=>array($this,'gridDataColumn'), 
        ), 
    ),
));
```

In your controller:

```
//called on rendering the column for each row 
protected function gridDataColumn($data,$row)
{
    $cellValue = "<ul>";
    foreach($data->classifiers as $classifier) {
        $cellValue .= "<li>" . $classifier->class . '</li>';
    }
     $cellValue .= "</ul>";
    return $cellValue;    
}
```